# XMLHttpRequest, $_POST is null when setRequestHeader is set

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I wrote javascript code with PHP, and wanted to send request using XMLHttpRequest. But always get $_POST null, when setRequestHeader is set. If I delete setRequestHeader, the $_POST is exist.

Here's my javascript code

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = new FormData();
params.append('workername', name);
params.append('address', address);
params.append('email', email);
xmlhttp.open("POST", "searchworker.php", true);
//Send the proper header information along with the request
//xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("workerResult").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    } 
};


xmlhttp.send(params);
```

The code result for

```
print_r($_POST);`
```

is

> Array (
>       [workername] => green
>       [address] => US
>       [email] => test@example.com )

I can receive $_POST value. But if uncomment the line

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

I will get this result

> Array (
>       [------WebKitFormBoundaryTBeUMaDsrWBBYRFB Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "workername"
>
> green
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryTBeUMaDsrWBBYRFB Content-Disposition: form-data; name="address"
>
> US
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryTBeUMaDsrWBBYRFB Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"
>
> test@example.com
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryTBeUMaDsrWBBYRFB--
>
> )

And all $_POST value is null.

So should I use the setRequestHeader? Cause I read on the web, that if we use open("POST",...) we should use setRequestHeader. What's causing $_POST cannot be received if setRequestHeader is set?

Comment: I think when `XMLHttpRequestInstance.send()` takes a `FormDataInstance` as its argument, it's already URL encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A FormData object, when posted, is formatted into a `multipart/form-data` body, not a urlencoded one. If you want to post the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you'll need to format the post body into an urlencoded string yourself.

```
var params = 'workername=' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '&address=' + encodeURIComponent(address) + '&email=' + encodeURIComponent(email);
```

Comment: Thanks. This work... Previously I've tried without the encodeURIComponent(), and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the Content-Type header. The browser knows how to set up a `FormData` request.

If you look in browser dev tools network and inspect the actual headers that are sent you will see it is set as something like:

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=-----11411516529451
```

Also note you can pass a form element into `FormData` and simplify having to do all the manual appends yourself

```
var params = new FormData(document.forms[0]);// or other appropriate dom query
```

Comment: So if we use FormData(), then there's no need to add setRequestHeader()...